# Check if a web element has a specific property and apply changes to the DOM according to the property's existence

Tags: javascript, iteration, polymer

I wrote this Javascript snippet for a Polymer fronted, it works without issues.

The only thing that it accomplishes is changing an icon's orientation whenever a user is clicking on any expandable-item (expandable-item is a specific Tag name).

Imagine a classic Operating System's folder tree display and the + or - icon that shows if a specific folder is expandable or not.

When the user clicks, the clicked expandable-item tag receives the expanded attribute.

The user can click on several expandable-item and all of them must remain opened or closed according to the user clicks and, clearly, also the icons related to the items must change accordingly.

Are there any ways that you could suggest to make it more efficient and/or shorter?

```
var expandedItems = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('expandable-item');

for (var i = 0; i < expandedItems.length; ++i) {
    if (expandedItems[i].hasAttribute("expanded")){
        expandedItems[i].getElementsByClassName("expandable-icon")[0].setAttribute("icon", "arrow:chevron-open-down");
    } else {
        expandedItems[i].getElementsByClassName("expandable-icon")[0].setAttribute("icon", "arrow:chevron-open-right");
    }
}
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: What task does this code accomplish? Please tell us, and also make that the title of the question via [edit]. Maybe you missed the placeholder on the title element: "_State the task that your code accomplishes. Make your title distinctive._". Also from  [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Also: Is `expandable-item` a tag name and/or a class name? If you are able to include sample HTML that might be helpful. Also, when does the JavaScript above get run?

Comment: To make this a good question, you should include the context for this code. Are you doing anything else besides just toggling an icon? Normally, some other functionality goes along with expansion/contraction, and we could give you more proper advice if we could see the related code.

Comment: Thanks @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ and 200_success, I perfectly get your point!
I hope the question is better now.

Comment: Well, I don't see any change to the title so, it doesn't look better to me. Also, the text added does not answer my question regarding `expandable-item` being a class name, tag name or both...

Comment: I applied other changes, @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ.
Thanks again for your input and patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search online for ["*queryselectorall vs getelementsbytagname*"](https://www.google.com/search?ei=PkfDXLWRJdLa-gTcto7oCA&q=queryselectorall+vs+getelementsbytagname&oq=queryselectorall+vs+getelementsbytagname&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l2j0i5i30l2.1762.4223..4480...3.0..0.61.447.8......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i304i39j0i13i10i30j0i13j0i13i5i30j35i39j0i7i30j0i7i5i30j0i7i30i19j0i7i5i30i19.TvVU3Y8HInU) and you will likely see results like [this SO post from August 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18247289/1575353) and [this post from September 2010](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2010/09/28/why-is-getelementsbytagname-faster-that-queryselectorall/). After reading those one can posit that using [`Element.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) instead of `querySelectorAll()` would be quicker, since the selector appears to merely find elements by tag name. Be aware that method returns a Live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) so you would need to put the elements into an array before iterating over them. There are some nice tools in [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) to do this, like using [the spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) or calling [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

---

If you keep the `for` loop, you could consider using a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) (also standard with [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6)) in order to eliminate the accessing array elements with bracket notation.

---

I am not able to find references to those attributes `icon="arrow:chevron-open-down"` and `icon="arrow:chevron-open-right"` but if those could be handled in CSS then you could eliminate the whole JS iteration block.

Comment: Precious fuel for my refactoring.
Thanks for your kind help :)